# Randomizing only some observations in Stata?

Tags: stata

My dataset is a larger version of this section:

| ID | Year | Units | Price | Type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Carrots | 2009 | 12312 | 3.25 | V |
| Carrots | 2010 | 10891 | 2.75 | V |
| Carrots | 2011 | 13232 | 3.50 | V |
| Carrots | 2012 | 9302 | 4.50 | V |
| Onions | 2011 | 728992 | 1.25 | V |
| Onions | 2012 | 937891 | 1.05 | V |
| Zucchini | 2010 | 9821 | 4.25 | V |
| Zucchini | 2011 | 8712 | 4.50 | V |
| Zucchini | 2012 | 10290 | 4.25 | V |
| Bananas | 2007 | 2341 | 2.75 | F |
| Bananas | 2008 | 3728 | 3.15 | F |
| Bananas | 2009 | 1829 | 1.50 | F |
| Bananas | 2010 | 4521 | 1.75 | F |
| Bananas | 2011 | 5438 | 1.50 | F |
| Bananas | 2012 | 1832 | 3.00 | F |
| Cherries | 2009 | 478 | 7.50 | F |
| Cherries | 2010 | 652 | 7.75 | F |
| Cherries | 2011 | 598 | 7.75 | F |
| Cherries | 2012 | 637 | 8.00 | F |
| Peaches | 2011 | 289 | 5.25 | F |
| Peaches | 2010 | 263 | 5.25 | F |
| Tangerine | 2008 | 21789 | 0.75 | F |
| Tangerine | 2009 | 29891 | 0.75 | F |
| Tangerine | 2010 | 19929 | 1.00 | F |
| Tangerine | 2011 | 20912 | 1.00 | F |
| Tangerine | 2012 | 18721 | 1.25 | F |

All observations are grouped by ID and alphabetically sorted, with all V first followed by F. I want to sort all type F observations randomly while keeping them grouped by ID, to get something like this:

| ID | Year | Units | Price | Type | rownum |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Carrots | 2009 | 12312 | 3.25 | V | 1 |
| Carrots | 2010 | 10891 | 2.75 | V | 2 |
| Carrots | 2011 | 13232 | 3.50 | V | 3 |
| Carrots | 2012 | 9302 | 4.50 | V | 4 |
| Onions | 2011 | 728992 | 1.25 | V | 5 |
| Onions | 2012 | 937891 | 1.05 | V | 6 |
| Zucchini | 2010 | 9821 | 4.25 | V | 7 |
| Zucchini | 2011 | 8712 | 4.50 | V | 8 |
| Zucchini | 2012 | 10290 | 4.25 | V | 9 |
| Cherries | 2009 | 478 | 7.50 | F | 16 |
| Cherries | 2010 | 652 | 7.75 | F | 17 |
| Cherries | 2011 | 598 | 7.75 | F | 18 |
| Cherries | 2012 | 637 | 8.00 | F | 19 |
| Tangerine | 2008 | 21789 | 0.75 | F | 22 |
| Tangerine | 2009 | 29891 | 0.75 | F | 23 |
| Tangerine | 2010 | 19929 | 1.00 | F | 24 |
| Tangerine | 2011 | 20912 | 1.00 | F | 25 |
| Tangerine | 2012 | 18721 | 1.25 | F | 26 |
| Peaches | 2011 | 289 | 5.25 | F | 20 |
| Peaches | 2010 | 263 | 5.25 | F | 21 |
| Bananas | 2007 | 2341 | 2.75 | F | 10 |
| Bananas | 2008 | 3728 | 3.15 | F | 11 |
| Bananas | 2009 | 1829 | 1.50 | F | 12 |
| Bananas | 2010 | 4521 | 1.75 | F | 13 |
| Bananas | 2011 | 5438 | 1.50 | F | 14 |
| Bananas | 2012 | 1832 | 3.00 | F | 15 |

My code is this:

```
set seed 4321
set obs 26
gen rand = uniform()
sort rand
```

But that only gives me a total randomization of all observations:

| ID | Year | Units | Price | Type | rownum |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Zucchini | 2010 | 9821 | 4.25 | V | 7 |
| Tangerine | 2008 | 21789 | 0.75 | F | 22 |
| Bananas | 2011 | 5438 | 1.50 | F | 14 |
| Cherries | 2011 | 598 | 7.75 | F | 18 |
| Tangerine | 2009 | 29891 | 0.75 | F | 23 |
| Bananas | 2008 | 3728 | 3.15 | F | 11 |
| Carrots | 2010 | 10891 | 2.75 | V | 2 |
| Cherries | 2012 | 637 | 8.00 | F | 19 |
| Onions | 2011 | 728992 | 1.25 | V | 5 |
| Peaches | 2010 | 263 | 5.25 | F | 21 |
| Carrots | 2012 | 9302 | 4.50 | V | 4 |
| Onions | 2012 | 937891 | 1.05 | V | 6 |
| Bananas | 2012 | 1832 | 3.00 | F | 15 |
| Zucchini | 2011 | 8712 | 4.50 | V | 8 |
| Carrots | 2011 | 13232 | 3.50 | V | 3 |
| Cherries | 2009 | 478 | 7.50 | F | 16 |
| Bananas | 2010 | 4521 | 1.75 | F | 13 |
| Cherries | 2010 | 652 | 7.75 | F | 17 |
| Carrots | 2009 | 12312 | 3.25 | V | 1 |
| Tangerine | 2010 | 19929 | 1.00 | F | 24 |
| Bananas | 2009 | 1829 | 1.50 | F | 12 |
| Tangerine | 2011 | 20912 | 1.00 | F | 25 |
| Zucchini | 2012 | 10290 | 4.25 | V | 9 |
| Tangerine | 2012 | 18721 | 1.25 | F | 26 |
| Peaches | 2011 | 289 | 5.25 | F | 20 |
| Bananas | 2007 | 2341 | 2.75 | F | 10 |

How can I only apply the command to type F entries, and how can I make sure they stay grouped by ID even after randomization?

Comment: On a side note, setting the seed is only 1 of 3 steps needed to make your randomization truly reproducible. Before `uniform()` you also needs to sort the data in a unique and stable way (see `isid ..., sort`) and you need to set the version (see `version`).

Answer (score 1):

You could take the maximum of the random number at the ID level. Here's a shortened example:

```
clear 
input str40 ID str1 type    
"Carrots"    "V"        
"Carrots"    "V"
"Zucchini"  "V" 
"Onions"     "V"    
"Tangerine" "F" 
"Bananas"    "F"    
"Cherries"  "F" 
"Tangerine"  "F"    
"Bananas"    "F"    
"Cherries"   "F"    
"Peaches"    "F"
end 

set seed 4321
gen original_order = _n - _N 
gen random = runiform()
bys ID: egen max_random = max(random)
replace max_random = original_order if type=="V"
sort max_random  
list ID type max_random
```

The output of the `list` command is below. The IDs are all grouped together as you wanted.

```
     +-----------------------------+
     |        ID   type   max_ra~m |
     |-----------------------------|
  1. |   Carrots      V        -10 |
  2. |   Carrots      V         -9 |
  3. |  Zucchini      V         -8 |
  4. |    Onions      V         -7 |
  5. |  Cherries      F   .3397298 |
     |-----------------------------|
  6. |  Cherries      F   .3397298 |
  7. |   Peaches      F   .4963937 |
  8. | Tangerine      F   .7204317 |
  9. | Tangerine      F   .7204317 |
 10. |   Bananas      F   .7838911 |
     |-----------------------------|
 11. |   Bananas      F   .7838911 |
     +-----------------------------+
```

I also set `max_random` equal to `original_order` for type "V" to preserve their order.  `original_order` is constructed to be less than or equal to zero so that type "V" always appears before type "F" in the sorted data. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

The already given answer provide a correct solution. But I think a cleaner solution that is easier to read and easier to modify if a new need comes up is to use `preserve`/`restore` to generate the random order only on the F-type observations, and then merge that random order back to the main dataset.

```
clear 
input str40 ID str1 type    
"Carrots"    "V"        
"Carrots"    "V"
"Zucchini"  "V" 
"Onions"     "V"    
"Tangerine" "F" 
"Bananas"    "F"    
"Cherries"  "F" 
"Tangerine"  "F"    
"Bananas"    "F"    
"Cherries"   "F"    
"Peaches"    "F"
end 

* Set seed 
set seed 4321

preserve 

  * Keep only F-type observation
  keep if type == "F"

  * Randomize the order of these observations
  gen rand = uniform()
  sort rand
  drop rand
  
  * Save these observations in a tempfile
  tempfile fobs
  save `fobs'

restore

* Drop all F-type observations and append them back from the temp file with the random order
drop if type == "F"
append using `fobs'
```